# How to fix 'CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED' issue when reporting achievement to google

Tags: java, android, google-play-games, cocos2d-x-3.x

When reporting achievements (achievement unlock/increment) I get error 'client reconnect required'. The achievement is unlocked when you check achievements popup but it resets when re-running the game.
This only appears when apk is uploaded(signed with release) but it works fine when just debugging (signed with debug).

Comment: Is this happening for all the users and all the devices or some specific android version or devices?

Comment: All Users and All Devices.. we are testing in alpha test and all test users got this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because you did not create the "Linked App" oauth2 client id in the google play console as outlined in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_3_generate_an_oauth_20_client_id)

> Warning: Make sure to record the package name and signing certificate that you configured in this step. Using a different certificate or package name in your application will cause authentication failures.